# problem using AJAX call in IE6 and IE7 -- I am asking the same question again, cause i did not get any solution before

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have this code, which is working fine in FireFox, chrome and IE8 but is it not working on IE6 and IE7.

```
function GetXmlHttpObject() {
  //var xmlHttp = null;
  try {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
  return xmlHttp;
}

function login()
{
    alert("Entered Login()");   
    var url="http://server.com/ALUauth.php";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=statechangedLogin;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function statechangedLogin()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        alert("Entered State Changed Login");
        if (xmlhttp.responseText=="Please <a href=http://server.com/ALUauth.php?login>login</a>")
        {
                document.getElementById("ALUauth").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
                GetEmailId();
        }

    }
}

function GetEmailId()
{   
    alert("Entered GetEmailId()");
    var url="http://server.com/GetPostEmail.php";
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=statechangedLogin2;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function statechangedLogin2()
{ 
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        alert("Enter State Changed Login 2");
        if(xmlhttp.responseText=="Login again")
        {
                window.location="http://server.com/profile.html";
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code in any other browser except for IE6 and 7 the output shows me all the alert boxes starting from: - Entered Login() - Entered State Changed Login - Entered GetEmailId() - Enter State Changed Login 2

and then the window location changes to http://server.com/profile.html

but when I run the same thing on IE 6 or 7, the code does not go into the statechangedLogin2(), and so the only alerts I get here are:

```
* Entered Login()
* Entered State Changed Login
* Entered GetEmailId()
```

I am unable to figure out why this issue is occuring. Why is it happening, and what should I change? The project is working absolutely fine on other browsers include IE8.

Can some one help me figure this issue of mine.

Comment: Is the browser producing any JavaScript errors (Tools->Internet Options->Advanced (tab)->Browsing (category)->Display a notification about every script error)?  Can the code be reduced (i.e. call GetEmailId), and still produce the error?

Comment: Please don't open duplicate questions, especially when the original wasn't even 24 hours ago...

Comment: Can you capture other calls to statechangedLogin2 that have a different readyState?  One concern I see here is that things won't end controlled if the call to get the email address fails.

Comment: Echoing ceejayoz -- It's usually considered to be more polite to edit the original question with additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello i am sorry to post my question again. but i was not getting any solution there so i tried to do this. thou i am sorry about it.

Anyways i was able to solve the situation with the help of my boss.

all i did was to give GetEmailId function its own session. something like this:

function GetEmailId()

{
alert("Entered GetEmailId()"); xmlhttpTwo=GetXmlHttpObject() var url="http://server.com/GetPostEmail.php"; url=url+"&sid="+Math.random(); xmlhttpTwo.onreadystatechange=statechangedLogin2; xmlhttpTwo.open("GET", url, true); xmlhttpTwo.send(null); }

I tried this and it works absolutely fine on IE 6 n 7 ... :)

Best Zeeshan

Answer (score 0):

Can you use JQuery, Prototype, Ext JS Base, or one of the other freely-available Javascript frameworks to do this instead?

There are a *huge* number of little browser inconsistencies to work around, so I don't recommend re-inventing the wheel--I know, I've done it before.