# Which part of my code isn't supported by IE 6

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, function, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to load a php file into a div via ajax. it works fine in all browsers but IE6 (It does not load the php file). I have a mandate that it needs to work in IE6 too. Please suggest corrections.

My **index.php** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML="<img src='loadingImage.gif'>";
if(XMLHttpRequest) var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
else var x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
x.open("GET", "other_content_1.php", true);
x.send("");
x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState == 4){
        if(x.status==200) document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = x.responseText;
        else document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = "Error loading document";
        }
    }
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="aside">This is other content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My **other_content_1.php** file:

```
<div id='other-content-1'>
<?php echo 'This text is loading via php command'; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: In what way does your code not work?

Comment: @Ted It does not load the php file.

Comment: I think with the need to support IE6 you can forget about almost all pleasing HTML5 inventions and instantly doubled your amount of work. Nobody but China is using it, see http://www.ie6countdown.com/ - and it is only supported for about one year until it's final death, although alternatives including IE upgrades are available.

Comment: @Sven Yes you are right. I am using some other workaround for HTML5 and CSS3 on modern browsers but here I need to support the basic layout for IE6 too as a lot of visitors of my client are from China and Taiwan and that is why he made it a mandate.

Comment: Do any errors appear in the console when the load fails? Is the request failing to reach the server? Is the call-back function being called? Have you tried calling `x.send("");` after setting `x.onreadystatechange`?

Comment: try inserting alert("end"); before the last } that would help knowing if there are any javascript errors before it (error = no alerts).

Comment: lol nowhere, that was just an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IE6 throws javascript error on this line:

```
if(XMLHttpRequest)
```

Here is the code that works on IE6 (and probably on IE5.5 too):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML="<img src='loadingImage.gif'>";

    var x = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var x = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    } else {
        // fallback
    }

    x.open("GET", "other_content_1.php", true);
    x.send("");
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(x.readyState == 4) {
            if(x.status==200) 
                document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = x.responseText;
            else 
                document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = "Error loading document";
        }
    }
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="aside">This is other content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So that means onreadystatechange worked in IE6 and IE5.5?! What about "The onreadystatechange event was introduced in Windows Internet Explorer 7." from Microsoft Docs?

Comment: @VikramRao - I'm surprised that this works on IE 5.5 and 6. According to the Microsoft docs, support for `onreadystatechange` was not introduced until IE 7.

Comment: I cannot find any source in the MS docs that says it's supported in IE6 but I've found that IE6 had some security issues related to that event: http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/39027/solution Maybe it was introduced in IE7 and added to IE6 with an update? Vikram: probably you should check this code on the oldest possible version of IE6. On the other hand - here is an answer where onreadystatechange was used and it worked on ie6 too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229821/problem-using-ajax-call-in-ie6-and-ie7-i-am-asking-the-same-question-again-c

Comment: Yes @Ted it does work on Even IE5.5 and IE6 I thoroughly tested the code thrice before accepting the answer. I am a noob in JavaScript. The code I am using was helped by 'heytools' in my other question. hence I will not be able to comment more on the technical issues. However thanks a lot for taking pains resolving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd576252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), support for `onreadystatechange` was introduced in IE 7; it won't work in IE 6. The work-around is to perform a synchronous request and use the results directly:

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", "other_content_1.php", true);
    x.send("");
    x.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(x.readyState == 4){
            if(x.status==200) document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = x.responseText;
            else document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = "Error loading document";
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    // assume IE 6
    var x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    x.open("GET", "other_content_1.php", false); // <- note change to last arg
    x.send("");
    if(x.readyState == 4){
        if(x.status==200) document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = x.responseText;
        else document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = "Error loading document";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @VikramRao - I didn't include your entire code; use this for just the part from `if(XMLHttpRequest) var x = new XMLHttpRequest();` down. Also, I was focused on the working of the request itself; to get rid of the error use `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)` instead of `if (XMLHttpRequest)`.